# Does someone recognize this font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I noticed a particularly nice math font being used in this paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1245332830.

Does someone recognize it? I've tried detexify but could not find it.

Here is an A:

[image]

a B:

[image]

and a U:

[image]

Comment: you have the pdf you do not have to recognise the fonts just use `pdffonts` utility or the font menu in many pdf readers (such as acrobat)  the document uses times roman and mathtime

Comment: The full list of fonts in that pdf is IFHKOH+Times-Italic 
IFHKPI+Times-Roman  
IFHLAJ+Times-Bold   
IFHLBJ+MTMI         
IFHLCK+MTSYN        
IFHLKI+MTMS         
IFHLLI+MSBM10       
IFHLNJ+MTEX         
IFHMBI+MTMIB        
IFHPLD+MSAM10 where you can ignore prefix such as `IFHMBI+` which denote document-specific subsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the used fonts (Times and Mathtime):

```
bash-3.2$ pdffonts euclid.aos.1245332830.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IFHKOH+Times-Italic                  Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     562  0
IFHKPI+Times-Roman                   Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     563  0
IFHLAJ+Times-Bold                    Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     564  0
IFHLBJ+MTMI                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    571  0
IFHLCK+MTSYN                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    577  0
IFHLKI+MTMS                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    352  0
IFHLLI+MSBM10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    360  0
IFHLNJ+MTEX                          Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     357  0
IFHMBI+MTMIB                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    364  0
IFHPLD+MSAM10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     371  0
```